# Find Best N Points From a Graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, genetic-algorithms

I've given a task and wonder if there are any better solutions.

Inputs of task are:

1. Distance of district pairs
2. Population of pairs

Goal is:

- Find **n** districts at which its population and districts **x** miles range districts' population is max.

Extra information:

- Unique district size is tens of hundreds.

As an example, if I pick up district **A**, population will be **A**'s population plus other districts' population which are less than **x** miles far away from it. Total population will be   **n** districts at which population is calculated as I mentioned.

What I've tried:

1. Brute Force
2. Generic Algorithms

What I planning to do:

1. A* Search

My question is, there may be any other solution (optimal if possible) instead of these one. i.e. sorting districts by their population, merging **x** miles nearest to them into one until I get **n** districts.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem. Can you confirm that it is the following? You have a non-negatively edge-weighted undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ in which each node $v$ represents a district and is associate with a non-negative integer $p(v)$ that represents its population. You are additionally given two non-negative integers $n$ and $x$. The goal is to find a subset $S$ of vertices of $V$ such that $|S| = n$  and $\sum_{u \in V : d(u, S) \le x} p(u)$ is maximized, where $d(u, S) = \min_{v \in S} d(u,v)$ and $d(u,v)$ denotes the  distance between $u$ and $v$ in $G$.

Comment: Could you explain the problem ? "Find n districts at which its population and districts x miles range districts' population is max" is not even a valid sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, there is no polynomial-time algorithm that finds an optimal solution to your problem unless $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$.
This holds even in the special case in which all distances are $1$, all populations are $1$, and $x=1$.

To see this notice that, given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and a non-negative integer $n \le |V|$, $G$ admits a dominating set of size at most $n$ if and only if there is a set $S \subseteq G$ with $|S| = n$ such that $\sum_{u \in V : d(u, S) \le 1} 1 = |V|$.

On the bright side, a simple greedy algorithm has an approximation ratio of $\frac{e}{e-1} < 1.582$: iteratively add to $S$ the district $v$ that maximizes the population that falls within distance $x$ of $S \cup \{ v \}$, i.e., the quantity $\sum_{u \in V : d(u, S \cup \{v\}) \ge x} p(u)$.

The approximation ratio of the above algorithm follows from the fact that you can cast your problem as a [weighted maximum coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem).
In this problem you have a set $X$ of elements and a collection $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets of $X$.  Each element $v \in X$ has a non-negative weight $w(v)$. You are given an integer $k \le |S|$ and you want to select a subset $S$ of at most $k$ sets of $\mathcal{S}$ such that $\sum_{x \in \bigcup_{S' \in S} S' } w(x)$ is maximized.
To reduce your problem to weighted maximum coverage problem pick $X=V$, $\mathcal{S} = \{S_v \mid v \in V\}$ where $S_v = \{u \in V \mid d(u,v) \le x\}$, $w(v) = p(v)$, and $k=n$

Since you can also reduce any instance of weighted maximum coverage problem to your problem, this is essentially the best polynomial-time approximation algorithm that you can hope for. The reduction is as follows: Create a complete bipartite graph $G = (V,E)$ with $V = \mathcal{S} \cup X$ and $E = \mathcal{S} \times X$. Each edge in $E$ has weight $1$. The population $p(v)$ of a vertex $v \in V$ is $p(v) = 0$ if $v \in \mathcal{S}$, and $p(v) = w(v)$ if $v \in X$. Pick $n=k$ and $x=1$.
You can easily see that you can restrict yourself to a solution $S$ that does not select any district in $v \in X$ (since $S \setminus X$ is as good as $S$ and $|\mathcal{S}| \ge k = n$). Then, selecting a subset $S \subseteq \mathcal{S}$ of districts corresponds to covering all the elements in $\bigcup_{S' \in S} S' \subseteq X$, and the population within distance $x$ of a vertex in $S$ is exactly $\sum_{x \in \bigcup_{S' \in S} S'} p(x) =  \sum_{x \in \bigcup_{S' \in S} S'} w(x)$.